# How to deal with changes to Search Bar in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a search bar in Xamarin.Forms, and in version 3.4 it used to look like this: [image]

But after I updated to Xamarin.Forms 4.4.0.991477, it looks like this:
[image]

I think what happened is the searchbar decided to create an outline around it, but didn't get rid of the underline it used to have so now the bottom lines are overlaying. I've seen suggestions of using a custom renderer but that seems overkill + I wouldn't know how to get rid of an element I don't know the keyword of..

Can someone help me either get rid of the border or the underline?? I'd like to know both if possible.

Thanks! (This is the android app, running Android 9)

edit: Forgot to add code

```
<SearchBar Placeholder="Search"
            FontSize="Medium"
            HeightRequest="50"
            Text="{Binding SearchText}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS and Android implementations for SearchBar are diferent, in iOS the SearchBar doesn't have the underline, and the underline can't be remove on Android unless you use a Custom Renderer, and it's not that overkill, is quite simple actualy.

---

1 - Create a folder for your custom controls and create a class and extend it from SearchBar like this:

MyApp.Mobile > *Create The Folder Here* > SearchBarNoUnderline.cs

```
public class SearchBarNoUnderline : SearchBar
{

}
```

After this, you only need the Custom Renderer for Android.

2 - Create a folder for your Android Custom Renderers in your Android Project and create a class that extends from Android SearchBarRenderer, like this:

MyApp.Android > *Create The Folder Here* > SearchBarNoUnderlineRenderer.cs

```
using MyApp.Mobile.Controls;
using MyApp.Mobile.Droid.CustomRenderers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SearchBarNoUnderline), typeof(SearchBarNoUnderlineRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Mobile.Droid.CustomRenderers
{
    public class SearchBarNoUnderlineRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                var plateId = Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
                var plate = Control.FindViewById(plateId);
                plate.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And that's it! now you can use you custom SearchBar in you XAML like this:

```
<controls:SearchBarNoUnderline Placeholder="Search"
                               FontSize="Medium"
                               HeightRequest="50"
                               Text="{Binding SearchText}"/>
```

And don't forget to add the reference for your custom controls folder:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Mobile.Controls"
```

---

And to remove the Border of the SearchBar, i use this little trick:

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="0">
    <controls:SearchBarNoUnderline Placeholder="Search"
                                   FontSize="Medium"
                                   BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                   HeightRequest="50"
                                   Text="{Binding SearchText}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Now your border should disapear, and you can use the parent StackLayout to define the BackgroundColor for your SearchBar

Comment: Thanks so much for this!!! For that removing the border of searchbar trick, will that change anything for the iOS app?

Comment: And why is there a BackgroundColor = red?

Comment: 1 - Nope, the control extends from SearchBar, so it will act like a normal SearchBar on IOS
2 - The color Red is just an example, since for the trick, you need removed the SearchBar BackgroundColor with "Transparent", the only way to give the SearchBar a BackgroundColor is to have a StackLayout that wraps the SearchBar and "Fills" the background behind the SearchBar, and since it's transparent, you will be able to see that color you gave to the StackLayout. Don't forget to mark it as the Correct Anwser if it solved your problem

Comment: I will! I'm adding the classes and files right now and if it works I'll mark it right away :)

Comment: I have a couple follow up questions, 1) Does it matter what I name my files? And 2) it seems like the project I'm working on already has a customsearchbarrenderer for the iOS search bar, would that affect my android one at all? Do I have to name the files and classes the exact same as the iOS classes ?

Comment: It's a little weird though, I'll make an edit with the code of the iOS SearchBar, but there doesn't seem to be a custom searchbar control in the project like you recommended I make

Comment: 1 - No it doesn't matter, just be sure that the name is the same when you are using it (for example, when defining the ExportRenderer, but it will trow you an warning if it isn't so no worrys), 2 - If the project is brand new, it shouldn't have any custom renderers added, i will add the File Locations to my anwser

Comment: It's not a brand new project, I'm working for a company right now it's a pretty big project haha

Comment: @chung then you should have already a folder for you custom controls.. [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SearchBar), press F12 with the mouse on top of the SearchBar and it will take you too the class, if it already exists, you only need to make step 2 and reference it in the export renderer, and i'm sure there is already an implementation of the Android Aswell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207366/discussion-between-ricardo-dias-morais-and-chung).